# Android architecture component navigation: toolbar back button missing, back not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I'm trying the jetpack navigation and can't show the navigation back button when I move to a new fragment.

NavigationActivity.kt

```
class NavActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation)

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val host: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_graph) as NavHostFragment? ?: return

        // Set up Navigation
        val navController = host.navController
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
        setupBottomNavMenu(navController)

    }

    private fun setupActionBarWithNavController(navController: NavController) {
        setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

    private fun setupBottomNavMenu(navController: NavController) {
        findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav_view)?.let { bottomNavView ->
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavView, navController)
        }
    }

}
```

activity_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".views.NavActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav" />
```

navigation_graph.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@+id/launcher_home">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/launcher_home"
        android:name="com.noisyninja.androidlistpoc.views.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/next_action"
            app:destination="@+id/detailFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:name="com.noisyninja.androidlistpoc.views.detail.DetailFragment"
        android:label="DetailFragment" />
</navigation>
```

code for navigation:

```
    /**
     * opens detail activity
     */
    override fun showDetail(view: View, me: Me) {

        var bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("key", "value")
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.next_action, bundle, null)
    }
```

[image: no titlebar]

As above when navigation to the second fragment the toolbar goes missing entirely and doesn't show the back button. 
Hitting the hardware back button also doesn't pop the detail view. 
The first hit has no effect, the second hit quits the app.

Comment: Can you include the `navigate` code you use to move to the detail screen? What does the hardware back button do if it doesn't pop the detail view?

Comment: added navigation code

Comment: As an aside, you can use `findNavController(R.id.navigation_graph)` to get a reference to your NavController from your Activity - no need to use `supportFragmentManager`, etc. Similarly, you can also use `bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(navController)` instead of NavigationUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: Your `DetailFragment` contains the line

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView<FragmentDetailBinding>(requireActivity(),
    R.layout.fragment_detail)
```

which is resetting the content of your Activity to only be your `fragment_detail` layout, wiping out the NavHostFragment and everything else.

You should be using `DataBindingUtil.bind<FragmentDetailBinding>(view)!!` instead.

**Original answer** (you should still do this, but the above answer is actually what solves the problem)

Your `ConstraintLayout` is missing quite a few constraints (your views should be a [vertical chain](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#constrain-chain), where every `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` has an alternative `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` on the other element, etc.).

Since you have a single set of three vertically aligned items, you don't need a `ConstraintLayout` - just a `LinearLayout` is enough:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".views.NavActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: still can't get it to work, the same issue. My project is at: https://github.com/ir2pid/AndroidArch.git
and branch: feature/components

Comment: Tracked it down - your DetailFragment calls `DataBindingUtil.setContentView`, wiping out the Activity's layout.

Comment: hey, you got it. Works now!

Answer (score 2):

`Override` this method in your Activity with `nav_host_fragment`

```
@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```